# How to call many Endpoint successively in WSO2 Integration Studio?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I was about implement a workflow of a Job using many calls mediators , each one it works perfect until i put them together so it didn't work and it give me this WARN in my console

```
[2022-12-19 16:55:03,026]  INFO {SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2022-12-19 16:55:03,027]  WARN {SourceHandler} - STATE_DESCRIPTION = Socket Timeout occurred after accepting the request headers and the request body, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_DONE, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = Connection between the client and the EI timeouts, HTTP_URL = /NumSequence, HTTP_METHOD = GET, SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 180000, CLIENT_ADDRESS = /127.0.0.1:57800, CONNECTION http-incoming-3 Correlation ID : dd34a03b-a3e6-4f6a-a254-230076b41246
```

this is my code :

The first API execute an SQL Statement of drop

The second API execute an SQL Statement of create

The third API execute an SQL Statement select

The forth API execute an SQL Statement of update

```html
<api context="/NumSequence" name="NumSequence" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://ebs-dev:8290/services/RADMINDataService/numseqdrop">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://ebs-dev:8290/services/RADMINDataService/numseqcreate">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://ebs-dev:8290/services/CRMDataService/ReadUsername">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <iterate expression="//accounts/account">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <payloadFactory media-type="json" template-type="freemarker">
                            <format><![CDATA[{
  "_postaddusername": {
                 "NumSequence":${payload.account.NumSequence},
                 "Prefixe":"${payload.account.Prefixe}"
                 }
}]]></format>
                            <args/>
                        </payloadFactory>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="post" uri-template="http://ebs-dev:8290/services/RADMINDataService/AddUsername">
                                    <suspendOnFailure>
                                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                                        <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                                        <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                                    </suspendOnFailure>
                                    <markForSuspension>
                                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                                    </markForSuspension>
                                </http>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>  
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Do your SQL queries take a considerable amount of time? You may need to adjust the client socket timeout of MI. Refer https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/references/config-catalog/#https-transport-non-blocking-mode

Comment: My sql queries don't take time ,it take time after implemented and exposed as API